# Improving productivity in debugging IntelliJ Idea

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, intellij-idea

I wanted to know is there any way in IDEA putting debuggers' breakpoint to previous row where debugger has just passed and re-run that scenario again. Because when debugging a loop, it's a bit tedious going to a UI doing desired action for handling that case again. I think such feature is available in Visual Studio. I've tried to google it but unfortunately I could not found anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've submitted an issue on IDEA's bug tracker but its status changed to won't fix with this comment:

> This functionality is not supported by the JVM. It's not possible to
>   implement it in IntelliJ IDEA without JVM support.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84257?projectKey=IDEA